# Проблема расчета рейтинга ajax rating

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Как вывести количество проставивших рейтинг людей по ID темы. Делаю так, складывает, но выводит подсчет по IDх2.

```
protected void BindRatingControl()
{
    int total = 0;
    int BrID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
    set.RatingDataTable dt = new  set.RatingDataTable();
    setTableAdapters.RatingTableAdapter da = new setTableAdapters.RatingTableAdapter();
    //da.Fill(dt);
   // da.FillBy(dt, BrID);
    da.ScalarQuery(BrID);


     if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
         {
             total += Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
            // Label2.Text = "проголосовало: [" + total.ToString() + "]";
         } 
         int average = total / dt.Rows.Count;
         //Label2.Text = "проголосовало: [" + total.ToString() + "]";
         Label2.Text = "проголосовало: [" + average.ToString() + "]";
     }
}
```

ScalarQuery- выражение

```sql
SELECT        COUNT(id) AS Expr1
FROM            Rating
WHERE        (id_client = @id_client)
```

Почему?

Comment: что значит IDx2? по другому ID? или результат оказывается в 2 раза больше, чем ожидалось? вы пробовали отладить по шагам?

Comment: Если честно - то даже из уточненного кода непонятно, в чем же проблема. Ваш SQL возвращает ровно **одно** значение (если в самописном `RatingTableAdapter`) ничего не поломано. цикл просто не нужен. можно просто вы вывести `dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()`). Или просто сделать `Label2.Text = cmdselect.ExecuteScalar().ToString()`.

Comment: это sql и это просто, мне надо, что бы это работало через objectdatasourse...и я не знаю, как заставить его работать именно через objectdatasourse.

Comment: если через SQL работает, а через objectdatasourse - нет, значит проблема именно в objectdatasourse - возьмите отладчик и пройдитесь по нему.